# python: summation of specific rows values based on location in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
df

    Name    A   B   C   D
0   Americas
1   Mark    1   2   3   4
2   Mat     5   6   7   8
3   ANZ
4   Pat     9   1   2   3
5   Pacific
6   Zack    4   5   6   7
7   Zoey    8   9   1   2
8   Zee     3   4   5   6
```

Here Americas is calculated as sum of row 1:2

ANZ is calculated as sum of row 4

Pacific is calculated as sum of row 6:8

**Note: These row numbers are constants, not dependent on any criteria but to be used as it is.**

The way to calculate total for individual columns is as follows:

```
df.at[5, 'A'] = df['A'].loc[6:8].sum()
df.at[5, 'B'] = df['B'].loc[6:8].sum()
df.at[5, 'C'] = df['C'].loc[6:8].sum()
df.at[5, 'D'] = df['D'].loc[6:8].sum()
```

Is there a way that i can do this without using 3 line code?

Resultant dataframe:

```
df

    Name        A   B   C   D
0   Americas    6   8   10  12
1   Mark        1   2   3   4
2   Mat         5   6   7   8
3   ANZ         9   1   2   3
4   Pat         9   1   2   3
5   Pacific     15  18  12  15
6   Zack        4   5   6   7
7   Zoey        8   9   1   2
8   Zee         3   4   5   6
```

Comment: Are the missing values empty string or nan?

Comment: @Ben.T: Missing values are nan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with finding missing rows with `isna` and `all`, and create groups with `cumsum`.  Then use this in a `groupby` and `transform` with the `sum`. Use `fillna` to fill the missing value.

```
g = df[['A','B','C','D']].isna().all(axis=1).cumsum()
df = df.fillna(df.groupby(g)[['A','B','C','D']].transform('sum'))
print (df)
       Name     A     B     C     D
0  Americas   6.0   8.0  10.0  12.0
1      Mark   1.0   2.0   3.0   4.0
2       Mat   5.0   6.0   7.0   8.0
3       ANZ   9.0   1.0   2.0   3.0
4       Pat   9.0   1.0   2.0   3.0
5   Pacific  15.0  18.0  12.0  15.0
6      Zack   4.0   5.0   6.0   7.0
7      Zoey   8.0   9.0   1.0   2.0
8       Zee   3.0   4.0   5.0   6.0
```

Answer (score 2):

First find lets find columns we need to fill by using a `isnull` boolean.

then we create a conditional column to groupby.

since you want your original dataframe back, we can use `iloc` to assign the values back along their index.

```
idx = df[df['A'].isnull()].index

#Int64Index([0, 3, 5], dtype='int64')

df.loc[idx,'Key'] = df['Name']
df['Key'] = df['Key'].ffill()


df.iloc[idx,1:-1] = df.drop('Name',axis=1).groupby('Key').transform('sum').loc[idx]

print(df.drop('Key',axis=1))

       Name     A     B     C     D
0  Americas   6.0   8.0  10.0  12.0
1      Mark   1.0   2.0   3.0   4.0
2       Mat   5.0   6.0   7.0   8.0
3       ANZ   9.0   1.0   2.0   3.0
4       Pat   9.0   1.0   2.0   3.0
5   Pacific  15.0  18.0  12.0  15.0
6      Zack   4.0   5.0   6.0   7.0
7      Zoey   8.0   9.0   1.0   2.0
8       Zee   3.0   4.0   5.0   6.0
```